# JPA - ReverseMappingTool mapped numeric to double

Tags: java, openjpa

after creating my entities with the OpenJPA's ReverseMappingTool I recognized that the tool mapped the db-fieldtype "**intversion numeric(9,0) NOT NULL**" of my postgres-DB to **private double intversion;** in my java-file. Since there is a zero after the decimal point I just don't understand why the field is mapped to double and not to int?

Change I change that? I want an int or an Integer in my Java-Class without changing the db-structure.

The point is, that the files are generated at runtime, so there is no way to check the structure and change it manually.

Comment: By the way. I tried the "typeMap"-Parmater of the the ReverseMappingTool with SQL Type "numeric(9)=java.util.Integer.class", but it does not work either

Comment: I debugged through the ReverseMappingTool and found out that the DBIdentifier "typename" sometime is null.
With boolean its "bool" with int or String its null.
Do I have to set it myself?